# How does Linux know what function to choose in rcX.d directory?

Tags: linux, init, sysvinit, rc

For example, I have the following script:

```
...
start(){
  echo "Starting..."   
  su - $ORA_OWNER -c "$ORA_HOME/bin/dbstart $ORA_HOME"       
  su - $ORA_OWNER -c "$ORA_HOME/bin/emctl start dbconsole"
  touch /var/lock/subsys/dbora 
}

stop(){
  echo "Stopping..."
  su - $ORA_OWNER -c "$ORA_HOME/bin/emctl stop dbconsole"
  su - $ORA_OWNER -c "$ORA_HOME/bin/dbshut $ORA_HOME"
  rm -f /var/lock/subsys/dbora
}

restart(){
  stop
  start
}

usage(){
  echo "usage: $0 {start|stop|restart}"
}
...
```

If I put this script in the directory /etc/init.d and after create a link in rc3.d with file name starting with `S` (start), How does Linux know that is needed to use function `start()`?

Comment: It would be helpful if you said what OS you use. Most of deskotp Linux distributions have switched to systemd.

Answer (score 3):

> If I put this script in the directory `/etc/init.d` and after create a link in `rc3.d` with file name starting with `S` (start), How does Linux know that is needed to use function `start()`?

I don't think it will. The function is internal to your script, and the script has to call it itself.

The other scaffolding surrounding that init script calls with an argument that tells what to do, `start`, `stop`, `restart` or such. The names of the links (`K*` and `S*`) tell what order to run the script and if they should be told to start or stop. Of course systemd does things a bit differently, but if I understand correctly, it can still support init scripts like that, and so has to pass them the correct argument when running them.

So then you see stuff like this in the init scripts:

```
do_start() {
    something here...
}
do_stop() {
    something else here...
}

case $1 in
    start)
        do_start;;
    stop)
        do_stop;;
    restart)
        do_stop;
        do_start;;
    *)
        usage;;
esac
```

The `case` in the bottom checks what the first argument is, and works based on that; that's the part missing from your snippet.

If you're writing a new init script, you should consider implementing is as a systemd service instead.

Answer (score 0):

It (Linux) does not. Linux is a kernel. The Gnu/Linux operating system knows.

In particular the `init` process knows. `init` scripts have to have `start`, `stop`, `restart`. These methods have pre-defined meanings, and are called at the appropriate time. These methods are the interface to your script, you have to implement them.

Comment: This answer erroneously conflates `init` and `rc` too.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the "S" you started the link with.  When a link starts with "K" (from kill), it will run the stop function.

Comment: Who will run it? What is *it*?

Comment: As you can see in the other answer, the init process, used to be /sbin/init.  Nowadays often crushed by systemd.

Comment: I know that. Your answer doesn't say that. Your answer says that *it* runs it.

Comment: Note the question is tagged `sysvinit` that is who runs it.

Comment: IMO OP asks what part of OS runs this `start()` part of this script and they think that it's *Linux* whatever that means to them.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk you are entitled to your opinion, but how your opinion would match the OP's "How does Linux know ..." ??

Comment: I don't get your question. But I was going to write an answer very similar to [what ilkkachu said](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4778/ctrl-alt-delor) in which I'd explain that Linux as the kernel doesn't care about your little init scripts and that it's init's (PID1) job to run correct part of the scripts. I also [asked](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/573090/how-does-linux-know-what-function-to-choose-in-rcx-d-directory/573093?noredirect=1#comment1066504_573090) what OS OP uses to make my answer more tied to his environment.

Comment: And BTW my system of choice which is Slackware also uses sysvinit so this question piqued my interest.

Comment: This answer, and the further comments, erroneously conflate `init` with `rc`.

Comment: @JdeBP please explain

Comment: @JdeBP is probably right, init starts the rc script for the requested runlevel, that scripts runs first the Knnxxxx scripts with the stop parameter, ordered by nn, followed by the Snnxxxx scripts with the start parameter.  I just don't know the meaning of the verb "conflate".

Comment: … and in the heyday of van Smoorenburg `init` there were in fact two major different `rc` architectures.  `init` and `rc` are two distinct programs, running in two distinct processes, and all of the behaviours ascribed to `init` across two answers here are in fact behaviours of (one form of) `rc`.  Enjoy https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/1998/12/msg02869.html for starters.